# Требования к современной верстке

Tags: html

Какие знания нужны в современной верстке?(желательно расписать по пунктам).
В общем интересует все что можно изучить, все что было бы полезным, различные материалы, видеоролики и т.д.

Comment: Не уверен что на данный вопрос можно ответить объективно... С одной стороны все что нужно знать это HTML и CSS. С другой стороны каждый может накидать кучу инструментов и методик, которыми он пользуется, но относить это все к ТРЕБОВАНИЯМ я бы не стал.

Answer (score 0):

Полостью поддерживаю @МихалРебров. Я могу вам написать список, только исходя из своего опыта и той компании, в которой я работал.

> Вы должны понимать, что на вашем месте работы, некоторые пункты будут просто не актуальны!

1. Семантическая верстка
2. Адаптивная верстка
3. Кроссплатформенная и кроссбраузерная верстка
4. Знание хотя-бы одного фреймворка (tailwindCSS || bootstrap 4-5)

Это то, что было у нас. Вот список того, что может понадобиться другим:

1. Какой-нибудь препроцессор
2. Возможно, какое-то базовое/начальное понимание JS
3. Видел частое требование - умение работать с photoshop
4. Понимать, как работает фигма

**PS:** Обратите внимание, что это только лично мое мнение. Вы можете быть с ним полностью не согласны.

***PSS для автора вопроса:*** Посмотрите вакансии, узнайте актуальные требования. Ведь сколько людей, столько и мнений